# How can I speed up flashing SD card ( wic Image)

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-wic

Flashing an SD card using dd is slow, is there another option to increase speed?

Comment: Did you call `dd`  with option `bs`, such as `dd bs=4M` will speed it up that the default is 512 bytes.

Comment: @Kai Thanks for suggestion, I will try and post the difference here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the bmaptool should increase the speed 10+ times.

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "wic wic.bmap"
bitbake <image>
```

Flash the device

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdX
oe-run-native bmap-tools-native bmaptool copy build-directory/tmp/deploy/images/<machine>/<image>.wic /dev/sdX
```